# How to add multiple form field types of choices for a question in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm creating a "Polls" like application. In this application there will be questions and every question will have single or multiple answers choices. ***The answer choice can be Text, Image, or Video.***

I have made one model called Question and different models for different choice types:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(QuestionCategory)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class ChoiceText(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ChoiceImage(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice = models.ImageField()
```

1. Is this a good way to design the models, or is there a better way to solve this problem ?
2. It doesn't look so intuitive in the admin side too, any suggestions on the admin side ? I looked at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial07/ but I'm still confused about combining the different choices into a better user-friendly way.

Comment: I have the same question but more complicated, and I expect a better answer.I added a cache Manager in Django Admin. Depending on the cache type,value could be Bool, User, Str, etc, Instead of using multiple fields, I want to dynamically change the type of the form based on choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go with same model (Choice). You can have a field named choice_type which selects the type of choice ('image','text','video').

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    answer_type_choices = (
        ('1','Text'),
        ('2','Image'),
        ('3','Video'),
    )
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_type = model.CharField(max_length=1,choices = answer_type_choices)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    choice_media = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

And while adding the data from admin or front you can have form with some customization that has validation rules in clean method ( require fields based on choice type, image field validation, video file validation ) based on choice_type.

Comment: This seems unpythonic, it would be better to use inheritance.

Comment: @ubadub There is nothing here seems unpythonic. It's based on how you implement the solution in better way.

Comment: As I explained, inheritance would be better. This is literally what inheritance is for.

Comment: I implemented both methods, inhertance and this one, inheritance was difficult on the admin side to customize. This one is easier on the admin side. I'm still confused about which approach is better. I'll do some more digging and accept one answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best way to do it, assuming a question could have multiple answers of the same type, e.g. one question might have 4 text choices and 2 image choices.

Depending on how you plan on using these models, you may want to create a model class called `Choice` and have the other models subclass from it.

Django's admin form is highly customizable. Since you haven't given us any specifics, feel free to explore [the Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, only problem is admin side is cluttered by model forms since I only need one of them depending on the type of choice.

Comment: @DrGeneral the admin side is customizable